# Do Urdu Numerals belong to the Persian Script?

Tags: writing-systems, numerals, persian, urdu

Do Urdu Numerals belong to the Persian Script and does Urdu use the same Unicode characters as Persian Language apart from Western Arabic numerals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand what you are asking. Urdu, like Persian, is written with Arabic script, with a few extra letters. The numbers are written with the Eastern form of the Arabic (originally Indian) numerals. So yes, they do use the same unicode coding.

Comment: not quite true.  U+0660 .. U+0669 are ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT values 0 through 9, while U+06F0 .. U+06F9 are EXTENDED ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT values 0 through 9.  the latter are the forms used in Urdu, I believe.

Comment: dang it, just reread q and a, you answered correctly.  oh, there's some added info there. ;)

Answer (score 1):

About Numerals, yes! Since those numerals belongs to Persian language, they are the same and even the same with Arabic except that number 4 number in Arabic which is different. Each one of these three language are in addition to be a separate language -especially about Arabic which is completely from a different language family- In written part there are several completely different characters which don't exist in the other one. (and of course Persian is not written with Arabic script, instead, Arabic is written with Persian script, There are some documentation that illustrate why (it's another topic...) look at this examples:

> Urdu: In Urdu in additional to Persian letters there are 4 characters that in Persian don't exist: ے , ں, ڑ, ڈ
>   Persian: In Persian there are 4 characters that in Arabic don't exist: پ ، ژ ، گ، چ

So it's **Urdu > Persian > Arabic**. And because even those similar Urdu characters often can't be understood either among Persian or Arabic people. you have to install each Unicode and language differently. 
I'm native Persian and speak and understand mostly Arabic and Urdu because of my studies.

Comment: "and of course Persian is not written with Arabic script, instead, Arabic is written with Persian script" - that is rubbish.

Comment: Ok then, try to write these letters:

Comment: گ ژ چ پ  So, how it could be rubbish?

Comment: Arabic script derives from Nabatean Aramaic script, not from Persian.

Comment: Dear @fdb I will wait for your reasons and explanation to prove "Why Persian is totally Arabic script" ?

Comment: So, Yes, as you know Arabic scripts comes from Nabatean Aramaic script, I didn't mention that "It comes from Persian script" !!! I said: " You can write all those Arabic scripts with Persian script!! just read the answer carefully!

Comment: unfortunately, I copied and pasted your exact words.

Comment: What i said "and of course Persian is not written with Arabic script, instead, Arabic is written with Persian script" doesn't necessarily explicit anything about root part of these languages individually because the main question of this topic was not about "From" or "root script of the other script"! But what you said: "Arabic script derives from Nabatean Aramaic script, not from Persian" It's exactly about root script and even implies you can write Persian totally with Arabic script!!!!

Comment: Armin, it is well-documented that Persian languages started to be written using the Arabic script soon after the Islamic conquest, replacing Persian cuneiform. To say otherwise is counter to what nearly everyone believes (Persians included). It is near impossible to find any evidence for your statement. To your particular point, Persian added those letters to the script in order to write sounds not already present in Arabic.

Comment: @Mitch, The first question, where was the the first place and origin of  Nabatean Aramaic script?

Comment: "soon after the Islamic conquest, replacing Persian cuneiform"?! Have you seen this tablet of king Darius, Kermanshah, Iran, 500 BC: https://www.scribd.com/document/103433279/Aryans-and-Aryan-Wezan,